# Testing ActionMailer with both paramaters and arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

How do you test a mailer method that uses both params and arguments.

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def invoice(invoice)
    @user = params[:user]
    ...
  end
end
```

None of these assertions will work:

```
  assert_enqueued_email_with UserMailer.with(user), :invoice, args: { invoice }
  assert_enqueued_email_with UserMailer.with(user), :invoice, args: [ user, invoice ]
  assert_enqueued_email_with UserMailer.with(user), :invoice, params: { user: user }, args: [ invoice ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been updated on Rails edge with this [PR](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/45752). You can now use the assertion as follows:

```
assert_enqueued_email_with UserMailer.with(user), :invoice, args: [ user, invoice ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check enqueued job

It's not so elegant like `assert_enqueued_email_with` but this method can't access parameters as arguments

```rb
UserMailer.with(user: user).invoice(invoice).deliver_later

job_args = ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter.enqueued_jobs[0][:args]

assert_equal job_args.first, "UserMailer"
assert_equal job_args.second, "invoice"
assert_equal job_args.fourth["params"]["user"], user
assert_equal job_args.fourth["args"], [invoice]
```

There is also [assert matcher for enqueued job](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveJob/TestHelper.html#method-i-assert_enqueued_with). And it's possible to check `ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob` with array of 4 arguments and passing mailer delivery to the block

```rb
assert_enqueued_with(job: ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob, args: ["UserMailer", "invoice", "deliver_now", { params: { user: user }, args: [invoice] }], queue: "default") do
  UserMailer.with(user: user).invoice(invoice).deliver_later
end
```